# Unable to create the Subdomain with specific name format in Dnn9

Tags: dns, subdomain, dotnetnuke, creation

How to create a sub site like subdomainname.domainname.com in DNN?I tried creating. It is giving DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error. Can anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: How are you trying to create the subdomain?  More details?

Comment: Like subdomainname.domainname.com.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you haven't actually configured the DNS for the subdomain.

Wherever you managed your DNS, configure a CNAME record for the subdomain, then add it to DNN as a new Site.